# How do I receive Response.Write?

Tags: asp-classic

This is an extremely basic question..

I've discovered that I need to use MSXML2.ServerXMLHTTP to perform a GET server-side and need to make the call between <% %>. I believe the only way to return information to the client is to use Response.Write

If I Response.Write a block of JSON, how do I "receive" it client side and process it? Sorry for the dense question, I'm just used to ASP.NET!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can write into a client side script block to use.

```vb
<%
'Make request
'Get response, assign a variable ( strResponse )
'e.g
strResponse = "{""key"":""value""}"
%>
<script type="text/javascript">
var JSONOBJ = <%=strResponse%> // an object created could be used on client-side
alert(JSONOBJ.key);
</script>
```